# MFC Highlighting any text editing box when clicked

Tags: mfc

I need to highlight all the text in the edit box by clicking the edit box
As the browser's edit box Site address

This button code works.

```
m_text.SetFocus();
m_text.SetSel(0, -1);
```

But the editing box event not working

```
void CMFCApplication99Dlg::OnEnSetfocusEdit1()
{
    m_text.SetFocus();
    m_text.SetSel(0, -1);
}
```

Comment: SetFocus is redundant. You already got the focus when you receive the Event!

Comment: What I'm doing to highlight all the text

Comment: On a side note, it is almost always wrong to call `SetFocus` in a dialog. [How to set focus in a dialog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040802-00/?p=38283/). In MFC you call [`GotoDlgCtrl`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/za5x8es7(VS.120).aspx) which sends `WM_NEXTDLGCTL` message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that this is the standard behavior. When you click into an edit control, the location is selected were you point to.

To overcome this behavior, it should be possible to post `EM_SETSEL` as a window message in your `EN_SETCOCUS` handler.

```
void CMFCApplication99Dlg::OnEnSetfocusEdit1()
{
  m_text.PostMessage(EM_SETSEL,0,-1);
}
```

PS: In your code the additional `SetFocus` is not needed when are inside the `EN_SETFOCUS` handler.